# How to have an angled line on a chart in live charts

Tags: livecharts

I'm trying to draw a trend line on a chart in livecharts using windowsForms and while I am aware of LineSeries(or GLineSeries in my case) it only goes through the points I select. Anybody know how I can make line go on forever like a AxisSection but angled

Ive found a solution where I calculate the path of the line with the straight line equation.

```
private void extendLineAcrossChart()
    {
        //lines is a list where I keep the indexes the lines I want to extend 
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            GLineSeries ls = (GLineSeries)ohlcChart.Series[lines[i]];
            ls.PointGeometry = null;
            extendLineAcrossChart((ChartValues<ObservablePoint>)ohlcChart.Series[lines[i]].Values);
        }
    }

    private void extendLineAcrossChart(ChartValues<ObservablePoint> ChartValues)
    {
        ObservablePoint PointFirst = ChartValues[0];
        double X1 = PointFirst.X;
        double Y1 = PointFirst.Y;
        ObservablePoint PointSecond = ChartValues[ChartValues.Count-1];
        double X2 = PointSecond.X;
        double Y2 = PointSecond.Y;
        double slope = (Y1-Y2) / (X1-X2);
        double coEfficient = Y1 - slope * X1;
        PointFirst.Y = slope * ohlcChart.AxisX[0].ActualMinValue + coEfficient;// Y = mX + n
        PointFirst.X = ohlcChart.AxisX[0].ActualMinValue;
        PointSecond.Y = slope * ohlcChart.AxisX[0].ActualMaxValue + coEfficient;
        PointSecond.X = ohlcChart.AxisX[0].ActualMaxValue;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide what have you tried so far? Please edit your question... Thanks

Comment: I figured it out shortly after. I've tried using other objects like mappers and seriesAlgorithms but couldnt get anything to work. The workaround I found takes the first and last points out of a line I'm extending calculates the slope and coefficient and then applies the straight line equation using end points of the chart. Will post my solution in a bit